# How can I use http parameters to create a new record in EE

Tags: channel-entries, php, http

I need to get the parameters from a http post url sent to my site and use the data to create a new entry in Expressionenegine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Channel Entries API. This will allow you to programatically create new Channel Entries.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_entries.html

The correct way to do it would be to create a custom module, and then have wherever this data is coming from ping that ACTion url.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/module_tutorial.html

Make sure when you do your database inserts for your ACTion ID, you make sure to set the `csrf_exempt` column to `1`, otherwise you will not be able to post to your website from a different domain. **HOWEVER**, you **MUST** replace that protection with something else. The simple thing would be to use something akin to an API key. Here's an example to run with for you custom module:

```
class My_module 
{

    $channel_id = "666";

    function __construct()
    {
        // instantiate your channel entries api
        ee()->load->library('api');
        ee()->api->instantiate('channel_entries');
    }

    function my_module_method_for_making_channel_entries()
    {
        // bail if you don't get your trusted api key
        if ( ee()->input->post('api_key') != 'random_api_key_youll_make_up' ) 
        {
            show_404();
        }

        // go ahead an use the channel entries api
        $title = ee()->input->post('title');
        $data = array("title" => $title);

        // save entry
        ee()->api_channel_entries->submit_new_entry($this->channel_id, $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you jrothafer, this worked exactly as i asked, except i had to use save_entry instead and also add session data.  however the script does empty previous data when updated with only some of the fields filled in.